# error: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration facebook login

Tags: javascript

Yes I saw there are a lot of questions about it but I tried everything I don't know why it is still not working for me

in the domain I tried: idareyou.t15.org and t15.org
both didnt work
in the site url tried: http://idareyou.t15.org/ and http://idareyou.t15.org/index.html
both didnt work

;\

you can see the code in the link:
[the facebook button](http://idareyou.t15.org/)

Comment: code is too long to add =\

Comment: i had to delete my answer, seems to be something else. really weird error indeed, everything looks fine imho...maybe you need to file a bug, or try to create a new app...